# Google places to stay within a certain location or radius

Tags: python, google-places-api

Can someone explain how I would find all casino's in Paris, France (location is in latitude and longitude) without using the radius which can go outside of Paris if the radius is too large? In other words, how can I stay within the borders of Paris? :D

```
from googleplaces import GooglePlaces, lang, types, Place

API_KEY = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ12345'
google_places = GooglePlaces(API_KEY)

query_result = google_places.nearby_search(
        location='48.866667, 2.333333', keyword='casino',
        radius=10000)

for place in query_result.places:
    try:
    # Returned places from a query are place summaries.
        print place.name
        print place.geo_location
        print place.place_id
```

Comment: Possibility: Use https://github.com/dsoprea/GeonamesRdf.

Answer (score 0):

Google place nearby search maximum 50,000 meters (31 miles) . if you try enter more than 50,000 it not work proper.

There is another way for find all Casino in a city.

- Open Google Maps .
- create 10-12 or more points latitude , longitude  value to trigger request.
- Then use a loop to find all places within these points.
- If you want more appropriate results, increase first trigger points for your requests.
- **It is just a logic i created in php.**

---

```
$triggerPoints = array("lat1,long1", "lat2,long2", "lat3,long3",....);
        
    foreeach(triggerPoints as $tP){
       $requestUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=$tP&radius=[YOUR_RADIUS_VALUE]&type=[YOUR_TYPE]&name=panera&key=[YOUR_KEY_HERE";
       $results = file_get_contents($requestUrl);
       //Do what you want with response JSON data
    
    }
```

**OR (second way)**

There is another way for find all Casino in a city. google provide Text Search Requests

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=Casino+in+Reno,NV,89501,USA&key={API_KEY}
```

**query = keyword + in + city Name**

for get city name using latitude longitude

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=39.52963,-119.81380&sensor=true
```

For more information how to get city name using latitude longitude

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start?csw=1#ReverseGeocoding

for more information about how to use Text Search Requests

[https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/search)